# Ajax load more - hide button if no more content

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a WordPress query (custom post type) and want the user to load more articles with a "load more" button (Ajax). To hide the load more button when there are no more posts I added an "else if" function:

```
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
var page = 2;
$('.loading').hide();
jQuery(function($) {
$('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function(e) {
    $('.loadmore').hide();
    $('.loading').show();
    var data = {
        'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
        'page': page,
        'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_posts"); ?>'
    };

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        if(response != '') {
            $('.ajax-posts').append(response);
            $('.loadmore').show();
            $('.loading').hide();
            page++;
        } else if(response == 0) {
            $(".ajax-posts").append("No More Records Found");
            $('.loading').hide();
        }
    });
});
});
```

The problem is that the button only hides on click:

```
} else if(response == 0) {
```

But I want to hide the button automatically when there are no more posts to load. So I have to do something like

```
} else if(response == 'last posts to load') {
```

Any idea how to do this?

EDIT - this is the query:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts_by_ajax', 
'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');

function load_posts_by_ajax_callback() {
check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'security');
$date_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$paged = $_POST['page'];
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 2,
    'post_type'         => 'termin',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'key'           => 'end_date',
        'compare'       => '>=',
        'value'         => $date_now,
        'type'          => 'DATETIME'
    ),
    'orderby'           => 'end_date',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'meta_type'         => 'DATE',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
);
$my_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) :
    ?>
    <?php while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post(); ?>

    <?php include(get_template_directory().'/termine-ajax.php'); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php
endif;

wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Just put `$('.loadmore').hide();` inside the `if (response == 0)` condition...?

Comment: I did, but it only hides the loadmore button on click when there a no more posts to load. I want to hide the loadmore button automatically after last posts are loaded so that the user doesn't have to click the button again to see there are no more posts.

Comment: What are you returning to the AJAX request when the end of the dataset is reached?

Comment: Maybe this is the problem that I only check the content on click - not on "end of dataset" reached. Any idea how to implement this?

Comment: Yep, just return a flag in the response to indicate if the server side reached the end of the dataset, then show/hide the load more button based on that

Comment: Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Not personally as I've never used Wordpress. I'm sure someone else will be able to help you, though.

Comment: If you could share your function `load_posts_by_ajax` that would help

Comment: I added the function that is in my functions.php.

Comment: Your request is a bit tricky: you want the "load more posts" button to disappear, as soon as the last post was loaded. But what about 10 seconds later, when another post might have appeared on the server?!? If you want to be absolutely certain about the availability of posts you would have to check the server regularly with a short Ajax request.

Comment: I only need to get the actual posts.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a max page number function. You can use that. But first you'll need to repeat the loop args on the page with the button. Step 1 set up just your args as a function, without the paged part (otherwise it'll come up with an error).

```
function ajax_args() {
$date_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$paged = $_POST['page'];
$args = array(
'posts_per_page'    => 2,
'post_type'         => 'termin',
'meta_query'        => array(
    'key'           => 'end_date',
    'compare'       => '>=',
    'value'         => $date_now,
    'type'          => 'DATETIME'
),
'orderby'           => 'end_date',
'order'             => 'ASC',
'meta_type'         => 'DATE',
'post_status'       => 'publish',
'paged' => $paged,
);

return $args;
}
```

Step 2 - adjust your load_posts_by_ajax_callback() function to load the previous function and add the paged part to it

```
function load_posts_by_ajax_callback() {

check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'security');

$paged = $_POST['page'];
$args = ajax_args();
$args += array('paged' => $paged,);

$my_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) :
?>
<?php while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post(); ?>

<?php include(get_template_directory().'/termine-ajax.php'); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php
endif;

wp_die();

}
```

Then step 3 - with where your ajax code is, you can call the original loop again (without repeating yourself, which is why we set it up as a separate function) and get the max page from that with $loop->max_num_pages; and impliment it into the ajax with an if statement with the page variable. eg if(page == max_num_pages; ?>) inside the response and before the page++

```
<?php $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$args = ajax_args();

$args  += array(
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args); 
$last_page = $loop->max_num_pages;
?>

var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
var page = 2;
$('.loading').hide();
jQuery(function($) {
$('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function(e) {
$('.loadmore').hide();
$('.loading').show();
var data = {
    'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
    'page': page,
    'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_posts"); ?>'
};

$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    if(response != '') {
        $('.ajax-posts').append(response);
        $('.loadmore').show();
        $('.loading').hide();

if(page == <?php echo $last_page; ?>) {

            $('.loadmore').hide(); 
  }
        page++;

    } else if(response == 0) {
        $(".ajax-posts").append("No More Records Found");
        $('.loading').hide();
    }
  });
 });
});
```